# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/.keras/models/efficientnetb0.h5'

Tags: permission-denied, efficientnet

I am getting this error while training Nan efficient net model.

```
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/keras-applications/efficientnetb0.h5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "efficient_net.py", line 45, in <module>
    base_model = EfficientNetB0(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_shape=input_shape)
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/XXXX/vevn37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/efficientnet.py", line 540, in EfficientNetB0
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/XXXX/vevn37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/efficientnet.py", line 406, in EfficientNet
    file_hash=file_hash)
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/XXXX/vevn37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 275, in get_file
    urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 257, in urlretrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/.keras/models/efficientnetb0.h5'
```

I have tried to change the permission of my python code:

```
chmod 777 code.py
```

It did not work.

Comment: Does the process writing your program have write permissions on that file location?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I have changed the permission of the code.py to 777 as I edited on the question. It did not work. Is there any other way of giving permission t the process?? let me know. thank you

Comment: The question is whether the _process_ has permissions on the '/home/ubuntu/.keras/models/efficientnetb0.h5' file. The permissions on the code.py file aren't really relevant. Whatever user is running your code (eg you in the commandline, an exec/fork from another process, a container, etc.) needs to have write permissions on that .h5 file. (Do you really need _write_ permissions? you could try not requesting 'wb' if that's the case.)

Comment: As you haven't shared a single line of code, it's close to impossible to provide help. What did you try to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?